# If $a < b + \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, then $a ≤ b$ proof problem.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> If $a < b + \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, then $a ≤ b$ proof problem.

I know that the result can be proven by contradiction.
proof by contradiction:
assume that $a>b$.
Then $(a-b)/2>0$.
If we set $\varepsilon = (a-b)/2$,
we get $a < b + (a-b)/2$.
Or, $a < b$. which is a contradiction.
Therefore, If $a < b + \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, then $a ≤ b$.

But this can easily be disproven with a counter-example.
If we take $a=1$, $b=0.5$ and $\varepsilon=3$,
we get $1 < 3.5$,
but $1 > 0.5$.
So how does this proof work? Am I making a mistake here?

Comment: Because the inequality needs to hold for every $\varepsilon >0$, which is evidently false here.

Comment: "for all $ε>0$". You just showed that there is one $ε$ (namely $ε=3$) for which it holds.

Comment: oh shit. yeah that makes sense

Comment: For any *specific* $\epsilon > 0$ the statement is *ALWAYS* false (just then $a =b -\frac \epsilon 2$).  But that statement is for *all* $\epsilon > 0$ *no matter how small*.  One way to think of is if $a$ is smaller than *all* possible numbers that are larger than $b$ then $a$ can't be larger than $b$.  (That should be obvious.  If $a$ were itself larger than $b$ then $a$ would have to be smaller than itself!). The *actual* surprising thing in this is that $a$ can actually be equal to $b$ itself....which isn't *that* surprising as $a$ is (obviously) smaller than any number bigger than itself.